# How to Use Customer Address template (set address in Customer Address Template )?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, shipping-address, customer-address

Thank you in Advance

I want to use customer address template to show customer template in format but I don't know how to do this ?

You can find this configuration :- **Store > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Address Template**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this section, you will see there are four fields that can be modified. They are: **Text, Text One Line, HTML, and PDF**

You can change the Html template text and move up and down where you want to set the position of this template and for the billing and shipping format on checkout page. In this case, we need to check the format in following file

```
-vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

-vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html
```